# Parsing hierarchical json to dataFrame in spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a json file structured in hdfs .I am trying to read the json file in my spark context.The json file format is as follows

```
  {"Request": {"TrancheList": {"Tranche": [{"Id": "123","OwnedAmt": "26500000",    "Currency": "USD" }, {  "Id": "456", "OwnedAmt": "41000000","Currency": "USD"}]},"FxRatesList": {"FxRatesContract": [{"Currency": "CHF","FxRate": "0.97919983706115"},{"Currency": "AUD", "FxRate": "1.2966804979253"},{ "Currency": "USD","FxRate": "1"},{"Currency": "SEK","FxRate": "8.1561012531034"},{"Currency": "NOK", "FxRate": "8.2454981641398"}]},"isExcludeDeals": "true","baseCurrency": "USD"}}

    val inputdf = spark.read.json("hdfs://localhost/user/xyz/request.json")
    inputdf.printSchema
```

The printSchema shows me the following output:

```
root
 |-- Request: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- FxRatesList: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FxRatesContract: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- FxRate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TrancheList: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Tranche: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Currency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- OwnedAmt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- baseCurrency: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- isExcludeDeals: string (nullable = true)
```

What should be the best way of creating a  dataframe/RDD of trancheList section in the json so that it gives me a distinct list of ID with there OwnedAmt and Currency  which looks like a following table

```
  Id       OwnedAmt       Currency
    123      26500000        USD
    456      41000000        USD
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way for getting this data.

```
val inputdf = spark.read.json("hdfs://localhost/user/xyz/request.json").select("Request.TrancheList.Tranche");
val dataDF = inputdf.select(explode(inputdf("Tranche"))).toDF("Tranche").select("Tranche.Id", "Tranche.OwnedAmt","Tranche.Currency")
dataDF.show
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the columns within the hierarchy of your DataFrame using the `dot` notation.

In this example, then the query would be something like

```
// Spark 2.0 example; use registerTempTable for Spark 1.6
inputdf.createOrReplaceTempView("inputdf")

spark.sql("select Request.TrancheList.Tranche.Id, Request.TrancheList.Tranche.OwnedAmt, Request.TrancheList.Tranche.Currency from inputdf")
```

Comment: No problem at all - glad to help! :)

Comment: it gives me a output like   Id|OwnedAmt|  Currency|

|[123, 456                           |[26500000, 41000000]|[USD, USD]  .How can i get rows for each Id like a tabular structure

Comment: sure ,i created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661859/getting-the-first-value-from-spark-sql-row/40662715#40662715 for my current issue