# Getting the first value from spark.sql.Row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have  the following json format :

```
{"Request": {"TrancheList": {"Tranche": [{"TrancheId": "500192163","OwnedAmt": "26500000",    "Curr": "USD" }, {  "TrancheId": "500213369", "OwnedAmt": "41000000","Curr": "USD"}]},"FxRatesList": {"FxRatesContract": [{"Currency": "CHF","FxRate": "0.97919983706115"},{"Currency": "AUD", "FxRate": "1.2966804979253"},{ "Currency": "USD","FxRate": "1"},{"Currency": "SEK","FxRate": "8.1561012531034"},{"Currency": "NOK", "FxRate": "8.2454981641398"},{"Currency": "JPY","FxRate": "111.79999785344"},{"Currency": "HKD","FxRate": "7.7568025218916"},{"Currency": "GBP","FxRate": "0.69425159677867"}, {"Currency": "EUR","FxRate": "0.88991723769689"},{"Currency": "DKK", "FxRate": "6.629598372301"}]},"isExcludeDeals": "true","baseCurrency": "USD"}}
```

The json is read from hdfs :

```
val hdfsRequest = spark.read.json("hdfs://localhost/user/request.json")
val baseCurrency = hdfsRequest.select("Request.baseCurrency").map(_.getString(0)).collect.headOption
var fxRates = hdfsRequest.select("Request.FxRatesList.FxRatesContract")
val fxRatesDF = fxRates.select(explode(fxRates("FxRatesContract"))).toDF("FxRatesContract").select("FxRatesContract.Currency", "FxRatesContract.FxRate").filter($"Currency"===baseCurrency.get)
fxRatesDF.show()
```

The output that I am getting for fxRatesDF is :

```
fxRatesDF: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [Currency: string, FxRate: string]
+--------+------+
|Currency|FxRate|
+--------+------+
|     USD|     1|
```

How can I grab the value of first row of Fxrate column?

Answer (score 33):

You can use

```
fxRatesDF.select(col("FxRate")).first().FxRate
```

Comment: This requires this import: `from pyspark.sql.functions import col` correct?

Comment: getString is not found in Function

Answer (score 25):

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.first) is the function that you need to use

Use like this:

```
fxRatesDF.first().FxRate
```

Comment: i tried that earlier ,fxRatesDF.first() gives this output [USD,1] and when you run fxRatesDF.first().FxRate it says FxRate IS NOT A member of sparche.sql.Row

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this way:

```
fxRatesDF.take(1)[0][1]
```

or

```
fxRatesDF.collect()[0][1]
```

or

```
fxRatesDF.first()[1]
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post but I got it to work this way `fxRatesDF.first()[0]`

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to just select row and column using indexing.
Input Dataframe:

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|    0|
+-----+
```

Code:

```
count = df.collect()[0][0]
print(count)
if count == 0:
    print("First row and First column value is 0")
```

Output:

```
0
First row and First column value is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for the one of the answers.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
fxRatesDF.select(col("FxRate")).first()[0]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
display(fxRatesDF.select($"FxRate").limit(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a line and a word is needed to solve this requirement.

```
fxRates.first()(1)
```

or

a line with two words

```
fxRates.first().getString(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Smells like Scala! I personally like to use the Dataset API.

```scala
case class OutputFormat(Currency: String, FxRate: String)

// assuming `spark` is available
import spark.implicits._

val fxRatesDF = fxRates
  .select(explode(fxRates("FxRatesContract")))
  .toDF("FxRatesContract")
  .select(
    "FxRatesContract.Currency", 
    "FxRatesContract.FxRate")
  .filter($"Currency" === baseCurrency.get)
  .as[OutputFormat]
```

Now, this becomes a little easier to work with.

```scala
// grab the product from the first row. No longer dealing with `Row`s, but `OutputFormat`s
val firstRow: OutputFormat = fxRatesDF.first
val example1: String = firstRow.FxRate

// or, you can map over and grab the row (again, type-safe)
val example2: String = fxRatesDF
  .map(_.FxRate) // Now, the row is just a `String`
  .first
```

If you don't want to deal with case classes, though, you don't have to. Just specify the row as whatever datatype you're working with. Case classes are nice b/c of IDE autocompletion and column names, but not always convenient.

```scala
val fxRatesDF = fxRates
  .select(explode(fxRates("FxRatesContract")))
  .toDF("FxRatesContract")
  .select(
    "FxRatesContract.Currency", 
    "FxRatesContract.FxRate")
  .filter($"Currency" === baseCurrency.get)
  .as[(String, String)]

val (currency, fxRate): (String, String) = fxRatesDF.first
val example3 = fxRate
```

I personally use this last way when I write unit tests. I care less about structure at that point, and typically just prefer one-liners/less code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this method:

```
fxRatesDF.select("FxRate").rdd.map{case Row(i:Int)=> i}.first()
```